# Intel Ethernet Driver Advanced Settings for Security/Privacy

Tags: network, configuration, ethernet, driver, intel

There are some settings found on Device Manager > Ethernet Driver > Advanced Tab.

Are there suggestions for any of these settings? or any suggestion to improve ethernet driver security?

```
Adaptive Inter-Frame Spacing 
Enable PME
Energy Efficient Ethemet 
Flow Control 
Gigabit Master Slave Mode 
Interrupt Moderation
Interrupt Moderation Rate 
IPv4 Checksum Offload 
Jumbo Packet 
Large Send Offload V2 (IPv4) 
Large Send Offload V2 (IPv6) 
Legacy Switch Compatibility Mode 
Locally Administered Address 
Log Link State Event 
Maximum Number of RSS Queues
Packet Priority & VLAN 
Protocol ARP Offload 
Protocol NS Offload 
Receive Buffers 
Receive Side Scaling 
Reduce Speed On Power Down 
Speed & Duplex 
System Idle Power Saver 
TCP Checksum Offload (IPv4) 
TCP Checksum Offload (IPv6) 
Transmit Buffers 
UDP Checksum Offload (IPv4) 
UDP Checksum Offload (IPv6) 
Wait for Link 
Wake on Link Settings 
Wake on Magic Packet 
Wake on Pattern Match
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, there's very little that involves configuring an Ethernet driver that can control security or privacy.  The job of an Ethernet driver is to get data from the kernel, where it's formed into packets, and turn it into actual signals on the wire.  The Ethernet driver doesn't generally have a lot of say in what data it gets; that job is handled by the kernel or the application.

Things that impact security are going to usually involve how the kernel handles packets and the network stack, such as SYN cookies or spoofed packet handling, or things at a higher level, like the use of TLS.  There could be settings that impact performance (such as checksum offloading) and therefore impact the ability of the kernel to handle more packets in a DoS attack, but generally those settings have sane defaults and the impact isn't going to be that substantial.  You are also not going to be able to stave off a substantial DDoS attack by controlling these settings anyway.

So overall, I wouldn't think of any of these settings in terms of security or privacy.  It's probably sufficient to make sure you're applying security updates on a regular basis and to think in terms of higher level things (e.g., using only HTTPS websites, avoiding running sketchy programs, and similar).